# Custom toolbar using ConstraintLayout in android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create my own custom `Toolbar` for my project. Currently I am using `RelativeLayout` to create it. But I wanna avoid deep hierarchy of `Views`. So I wanna create it using `ConstrainLayout`. How can I achieve the following in `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]

**Code for the above layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/customAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarCloseButton"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbarCloseButton"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Puzzle" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coinIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_single_coin"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/prizeSize"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circular_background"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:freezesText="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:maxEms="20"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="6sp"
                    tools:text="100" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

How this can be done in `ConstraintLayout` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your custom layout inside the toolbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <!-- your custom layout here --> 
    <include android:id="@+id/actionBar" layout="@layout/action_bar_layout"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: Be careful with that: The resource `"@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"` is marked as private.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple layout. You can see my code to improve your layout. Hope it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00ffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I am more concerned about the `ImageView` with the `TextView` below it (Coin Image).

Comment: @Hiren Why concerned? Unlike other layouts, in `Constraintlayout` if you want something to be above than the previous widget then it should be declared after the previous widget. <- Was this your concern?

Comment: @Hiren: I think it isn't your problem. The problem is that you should understand how to make a layout with `ConstrauntLayout`. My answer just is an example. Depends on your purpose you have to modify it by yourself.

Comment: BTW, In this first ImageView is the Cross button and Second ImageView is the Coin button.

Comment: This is the required answer. I would've posted similar.

Comment: If you see the second `ImageView`. Its having one `ImageView` and a `TextView` below it. I am using one more `RelativeLayout` for that..that I want to avoid.

Comment: The Base code which you have provided @LQGioan that I was able to create but I am stuck with the problem with the inner `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Hiren: try to use ` app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` and 'app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"' in the second `ImageView` in my answer for inner `RelativeLayout` (sorry, I haven't tested it). Hope it works

Comment: Thanks.. but if possible do try to provide the exact of the above `Toolbar`